# how do you pass string variables to build job parameters in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

for example:

```
build job: '../downstream_job', parameters: "$variables"
```

how do you pass the variables ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the format:

```
build job: 'job_name', parameters: [string(name: 'yourStringParameter', value: "$variable_name")]
```

You can use the pipeline syntax to generate this code.

Comment: I know this way to pass but my requirement is to pass the whole parameters value ? rather than just 'value' variable

Comment: I don't think so. No.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple jenkins job "Echo Params Environment and branch" which echos two parameters it takes: Environment and branch

Then I created this pipeline which calls the job and also has the same two parameters . There are a few extra lines as I was playing with variables but you can see that you can either explicitly define the parameters list (job1) or reference list2 to use as the parameters (job2) - don't use "$list2" - that behaves as a string rather than a list if you do that - so just reference the groovy list variable list2 and it should work fine.

```
stage('STEP # 1 : Echo parameters') {
  String env_name = "${params.Environment}"
  String branch_name = "${params.branch}"
  println "params are branch $branch_name deploy on $env_name"
  def list2 = [string(name: 'Environment', value: "$env_name"), 
               string(name: 'branch',      value: "$branch_name")]
  println "List2 is $list2"

  // This works with explicit parameter list defined
  def job1 = build job:'Echo Params Environment and branch', 
              parameters: [string(name: 'Environment', value: "$env_name"), 
                           string(name: 'branch',      value: "$branch_name")]
                 
  def result1 = job1.rawBuild.log
  println "result1 = ${result1}"

  // This also works - note no $ and no " around list2 
  def job2 = build job:'Echo Params Environment and branch', parameters: list2
  def result2 = job2.rawBuild.log
  println "result2 = ${result2}"
}
```